# How to hide top and bottom part of image in a bootstrap card

Tags: html, css

I am using bootstrap card to show list of videos and for videos i am using YouTube Video thumbnail (hqdefault.jpg). since this thumbnail show black strip on top and bottom on the image which i want to hide as it doesn't look good.

i tried .card-img-top{position:absolute; top:-30px; } but it breaks the whole design

https://codepen.io/KGuide/pen/MWyZYyb?editors=0100

```
<div class="container py-5">
       
    <div class="row pb-5 mb-4">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-lg-0">
            <!-- Card-->
            <div class="card shadow-sm border-0 rounded">
                <div class="card-body p-0"><img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/Aymrnzianf0/hqdefault.jpg" alt="" class="w-100 card-img-top">
                    <div class="p-4">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">Mark Rockwell</h5>
                        <p class="small text-muted">CEO - Consultant</p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-lg-0">
            <!-- Card-->
            <div class="card shadow-sm border-0 rounded">
                <div class="card-body p-0"><img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/EMVPpPE_Bx4/hqdefault.jpg" alt="" class="w-100 card-img-top">
                    <div class="p-4">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">Mark Rockwell</h5>
                        <p class="small text-muted">CEO - Consultant</p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-lg-0">
            <!-- Card-->
            <div class="card shadow-sm border-0 rounded">
                <div class="card-body p-0"><img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/22BXPLkyocw/hqdefault.jpg" alt="" class="w-100 card-img-top">
                    <div class="p-4">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">Mark Rockwell</h5>
                        <p class="small text-muted">CEO - Consultant</p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-lg-0">
            <!-- Card-->
            <div class="card shadow-sm border-0 rounded">
                <div class="card-body p-0"><img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/Aymrnzianf0/hqdefault.jpg" alt="" class="w-100 card-img-top">
                    <div class="p-4">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">Mark Rockwell</h5>
                        <p class="small text-muted">CEO - Consultant</p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: can you try custom css to crop the top and bottom portion of image?

Comment: @NIKHILCHANDRAROY, never heard of cropping image using css that would make it easy..

Comment: @NIKHILCHANDRAROY, I will try it and also check browser support also

Answer (score 1):

overflow hidden with margin negative % is best solution:

```css
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #fafafa;
}


.social-link {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #666;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
}

.social-link:hover, .social-link:focus {
    background: #ddd;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #555;
}

.progress {
    height: 10px;
}
.card-body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* update: */
.photo {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.photo img {
  margin: -10% 0 -10% 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container py-5">
       
    <div class="row pb-5 mb-4">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-lg-0">
            <!-- Card-->
            <div class="card shadow-sm border-0 rounded">
                <div class="card-body p-0">
                  <div class="photo">
                    <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/Aymrnzianf0/hqdefault.jpg" alt="" class="w-100 card-img-top">
                  </div>
                  
                    <div class="p-4">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">Mark Rockwell</h5>
                        <p class="small text-muted">CEO - Consultant</p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-lg-0">
            <!-- Card-->
            <div class="card shadow-sm border-0 rounded">
                <div class="card-body p-0">
                  <div class="photo">
                    <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/EMVPpPE_Bx4/hqdefault.jpg" alt="" class="w-100 card-img-top">
                  </div>
                  
                    <div class="p-4">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">Mark Rockwell</h5>
                        <p class="small text-muted">CEO - Consultant</p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-lg-0">
            <!-- Card-->
            <div class="card shadow-sm border-0 rounded">
                <div class="card-body p-0">
                  <div class="photo">
                    <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/22BXPLkyocw/hqdefault.jpg" alt="" class="w-100 card-img-top">
                  </div>
                  
                    <div class="p-4">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">Mark Rockwell</h5>
                        <p class="small text-muted">CEO - Consultant</p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-lg-0">
            <!-- Card-->
            <div class="card shadow-sm border-0 rounded">
                <div class="card-body p-0">
                  <div class="photo">
                    <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/Aymrnzianf0/hqdefault.jpg" alt="" class="w-100 card-img-top">
                  </div>
                  
                    <div class="p-4">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">Mark Rockwell</h5>
                        <p class="small text-muted">CEO - Consultant</p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by adding a background image

```css
.bg {
    height: 235px;
    background-position: center;
    background-position-x: inherit;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 134%;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container py-5">
       
    <div class="row pb-5 mb-4">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-lg-0">
            <!-- Card-->
            <div class="card shadow-sm border-0 rounded">
                <div class="card-body p-0">
                <div style="background-image: url('https://img.youtube.com/vi/Aymrnzianf0/hqdefault.jpg');" alt="" class="w-100 card-img-top bg">
                </div>
                    <div class="p-4">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">Mark Rockwell</h5>
                        <p class="small text-muted">CEO - Consultant</p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-lg-0">
            <!-- Card-->
            <div class="card shadow-sm border-0 rounded">
                <div class="card-body p-0">
                <div style="background-image: url('https://img.youtube.com/vi/EMVPpPE_Bx4/hqdefault.jpg');" alt="" class="w-100 card-img-top bg">
                </div>
                    <div class="p-4">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">Mark Rockwell</h5>
                        <p class="small text-muted">CEO - Consultant</p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-lg-0">
            <!-- Card-->
            <div class="card shadow-sm border-0 rounded">
                <div class="card-body p-0">
                <div style="background-image: url('https://img.youtube.com/vi/22BXPLkyocw/hqdefault.jpg');" alt="" class="w-100 card-img-top bg">
                </div>
                    <div class="p-4">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">Mark Rockwell</h5>
                        <p class="small text-muted">CEO - Consultant</p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-lg-0">
            <!-- Card-->
            <div class="card shadow-sm border-0 rounded">
                <div class="card-body p-0">
                <div style="background-image: url('https://img.youtube.com/vi/Aymrnzianf0/hqdefault.jpg');" alt="" class="w-100 card-img-top bg">
                </div>
                    <div class="p-4">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">Mark Rockwell</h5>
                        <p class="small text-muted">CEO - Consultant</p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is two things that you can do:

1. Override bootstraps `col` and `row` classes, which means play around with the height until you get the image to be `1280`x`720` (normal youtube thumbnail dimension)
2. (**Recommended**). You can make your own rows and cols by using `grid-template-areas`. Which is a very powerful css property that simply lets you write out your layout.

```
grid-template-areas: 'youtube_video youtube_video youtube_video';
```

It is a simple css property that is very easy to learn and also very powerful.

[check out grid-template-areas on the tryit editor](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_grid-template-areas3)

After you make your own `col` and `row` don't forget to make the image width and height:
`1280` x `720`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried 2 way but I see margin top and bottom also good.
`clip-path: polygon(0 13%, 100% 13%, 100% 87%, 0 87%);`
clip-path will crop the top and bottom portion.
Another one is using background.

```css
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #fafafa;
}


.social-link {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #666;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
}

.social-link:hover, .social-link:focus {
    background: #ddd;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #555;
}

.progress {
    height: 10px;
}

.card-img-top{
 background: var(--i) no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100% 140%;
  display: block;
  min-height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  
  
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container py-5">

  <div class="row pb-5 mb-4">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-lg-0">
      <!-- Card-->
      <div class="card shadow-sm border-0 rounded">
        <div class="card-body p-0"><img src="" style="--i:url(https://img.youtube.com/vi/Aymrnzianf0/hqdefault.jpg)" alt="" class="w-100 card-img-top">
          <div class="p-4">
            <h5 class="mb-0">Mark Rockwell</h5>
            <p class="small text-muted">CEO - Consultant</p>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-lg-0">
      <!-- Card-->
      <div class="card shadow-sm border-0 rounded">
        <div class="card-body p-0">
          <img src="" style="--i:url(https://img.youtube.com/vi/EMVPpPE_Bx4/hqdefault.jpg)" alt="" class="w-100 card-img-top">
          <div class="p-4">
            <h5 class="mb-0">Mark Rockwell</h5>
            <p class="small text-muted">CEO - Consultant</p>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-lg-0">
      <!-- Card-->
      <div class="card shadow-sm border-0 rounded">
        <div class="card-body p-0"><img src="" style="--i:url(https://img.youtube.com/vi/22BXPLkyocw/hqdefault.jpg)" alt="" class="w-100 card-img-top">
          <div class="p-4">
            <h5 class="mb-0">Mark Rockwell</h5>
            <p class="small text-muted">CEO - Consultant</p>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-lg-0">
      <!-- Card-->
      <div class="card shadow-sm border-0 rounded">
        <div class="card-body p-0"><img src="" style="--i:url(https://img.youtube.com/vi/Aymrnzianf0/hqdefault.jpg)" alt="" class="w-100 card-img-top">
          <div class="p-4">
            <h5 class="mb-0">Mark Rockwell</h5>
            <p class="small text-muted">CEO - Consultant</p>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I have using background image in couple of projects, i wanted to try approach without background image.

Answer (score 0):

[Attached screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2RiY.jpg)

What I have done is, wrap your img into one figure tag and then gave height to the figure tag. Then on image give height 100% and object-fit cover. Black bg will automatically hide.

```
<figure>
  <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/Aymrnzianf0/hqdefault.jpg" alt="" 
  class="w-100 card-img-top">
</figure>

figure {
  margin: 0;
  height: 284px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

figure img {
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```